# Zip and archive to other directory

Tags: shell-script, tar, archive

I have some 250 CSV source files in the incoming directory.

My task is to merge those CSV files and generate a file like `Merge_`.
the Informatica Job will then pick the merge file as the source and work.

Now the merge part is taken care of. I want all the CSV files to be  zipped and archived to another directory say `/source/archive` as soon as the merge file is generated.

Also, I want the `Merge_` file to remain like that and untouched.

I am aware of how to zip and tar separately but not sure how to combine both and move to some other directory.

I am trying to use something like this but it's not working:

```
tar -czvf All_Files.tar.gz *.csv  /Source/Archive --remove-files --exclude Merge_file_1.csv, Merge_File_2.csv
```

Expecting it to tar and zip then move the file to /source/archive and remove the original files except the merge files

Comment: Both zip and tar have options to write to a specific file: `zip --outfile somewhere` or `tar -cf somewhere`, where `somewhere` is a full path that can be outside your workingdir.  You could `tar --to-stdout` and redirect stdout where you need it.  Or you could leave the zipping to tar `tar czf somewhere Merge_*`.

Comment: Added the command i am trying but first off all, it's creating tar file in same directory and error like "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" and i also want to exclude the two merge files from getting removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in two commands, as `--remove-files` will ignore `--exclude`.

```bash
tar -czvf ../All_Files.tar.gz --exclude 'Merge_*' *.csv && \
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -not -name 'Merge_*' -delete
```

The message `"tar: Removing leading '/' from member names"` is NOT an error, but tar working as intended.

Please note that `--exclude` takes a pattern (e.g. `'Merge_*'`), not a comma-separated list.  You need to put it prior to the files you want to exclude from the archive, otherwise the `Merge_`-files will end up in your archive.

Comment: can i run this together in the script as you have used && \. Btw what does && \ do?

Comment: `&&` will only run the command following it íf the previous command was successful.  So if tar fails for some reason, your csv-files will not be deleted.  The backslash tells the shell that the command is continued on the next line.  It is not *needed*, but it makes the command easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot mark !! Much Appreciated for your help. :)